# При выборке из базы русские буквы отображаются как знаки вопросов

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

При GET запросе все JSON все русские буквы превратились в знаки вопросов.

PHP - cкрипт:

```
 <?php
class Sql{


public $password = '****';
public $user = '****';
public $database = '****';
public $host = 'localhost';


var $querydb;
public $response;

function Connect_db($query, $dowhile = false){

/*ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);*/

// подключаемся к серверу
$link = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this-
>database) 
 or die(trim("Error") . mysqli_error($link));
$this->querydb = $query;

$result = mysqli_query($link, $this->querydb) or die(); 

if($result)
{

 unset($this->response);

if($dowhile == true){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){



//return $row;

$this->response[] = $row;
}


}
else{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $this->response = $row;
}

return $this->response;
}

// закрываем подключение
mysqli_free_result($row);
mysqli_close($link);
}

}


$sql = new Sql;
$duck = $sql->Connect_db("SELECT * FROM base_data LIMIT 0, 99",true);
$data = array("company"=>"HeaSoft", "copyright"=>"© 2017, HeaSoft", 
"news"=>$duck);

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

JSON выдается вот такой:
{"company":"HeaSoft","copyright":"\u00a9 2017, HeaSoft","news":[{"id":"1","name":"?????? ???????????? ??????????","title":"?????? ???????????? ??????????","author":"????? ?.?.","created_at":null,"content":"HeaSoft ????????? ???? ??????????? ????????? ??????! ??????????? ???? ? ????!","bigcontent":"simple","type":null,"urlToImage":null,"likes":"0"},{"id":"2","name":"?????????? ? GooglePlay","title":"?????????? ? GooglePlay","author":"????? ?.?","created_at":"today","content":"???-??? ???? ?????? ????????? ?????????? ????? ???????????? ? GooglePlay ?? ???????? ?????????. ???? ???????????","bigcontent":"???-??? ???? ?????? ????????? ?????????? ????? ???????????? ? GooglePlay ?? ???????? ?????????. ???? ???????????","type":"simple","urlToImage":"googleplay","likes":"0"},{"id":"3","name":"????? ??????. ????????.","title":"????? ??????. ????????.","author":"????? ?.?","created_at":"today","content":"????? ?????????? ????? ??? ?????? ??????????! ?????? ??? ?????? ?????? ????? ??????? ????????!","bigcontent":"????? ?????????? ????? ??? ?????? ??????????! ?????? ??? ?????? ?????? ????? ??????? ????????!","type":"simple","urlToImage":"pictures","likes":"0"},{"id":"4","name":"?????????? ?? ???? ???? ?????????.","title":"\u0000?????????? ?? ???? ???? ?????????.","author":"????? ?.?","created_at":"today","content":"?????????? ?????? ??????? ?????????? ?????????? ????????? ?????????. ????? ?? ??????? ??????????? ???????? ?? ??????? ????? ?? ??????????.","bigcontent":"?????????? ?????? ??????? ?????????? ?????????? ????????? ?????????. ????? ?? ??????? ??????????? ???????? ?? ??????? ????? ?? ??????????.","type":"simple","urlToImage":"googlepub","likes":"0"},{"id":"5","name":"?????? ????? ??????????! ?? ??????? ?????.","title":"\u0000?????? ????? ??????????! ?? ??????? ?????.","author":"????? ?.?","created_at":"today","content":"????? ?????????? ????? ???-??? ??????, ??? ???????????? ?????? ??????? ?????. ????? ?? ??????? ????? ????? ?????????? ????????, ?? ??? ?? ?????.","bigcontent":"????? ?????????? ????? ???-??? ??????, ??? ???????????? ?????? ??????? ?????. ????? ?? ??????? ????? ????? ?????????? ????????, ?? ??? ?? ?????.","type":"simple","urlToImage":"like","likes":"0"}]}

И вот база данных:[База данных](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s1gZ.jpg)

Структура БД:[image: Структура]

Comment: `var_dump($data);` что выведет вместо `echo json_encode($data);`? И какая кодировка страницы при этом будет в браузере?

Comment: @Visman, HeaSoft" ["news"]=> array(5) { [0]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(30) "?????? ???????????? ??????????"
Кодировка через "посмотреть код" не указывается

Comment: Кодировку смотреть надо в меню Вид - Кодировка текста (страницы). В базе текст читаем или тоже знаки вопроса прописаны? Перед `$this->querydb = $query;` добавьте `mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');`

Comment: @Visman, Да, читаем, Все, заработало. Добавляй ответ и я его помечу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кодировка соединения с базой не установлена.
После подключения к базе

```
$link = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database)
 or trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error());
```

следует установить кодировку соединения командой

```
mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');
```

Comment: А зачем здесь был trim?

Comment: @Ипатьев, а вы зря мой ответ поменяли. trim() и die() написаны в коде у автора вопроса, который тут приведен как якорь для mysqli_set_charset().

Comment: Как раз не зря. Люди копи-пастят код, и лучше чтобы он был правильным. Понял, спасибо, виновата моя невнимательность.

Comment: ОСОБЕННО, если на вопрос ведут ссылки из дубликатов