# Необходимо из данных получаемых из базы получать их в кодировке UTF8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

Устроено все так:
Есть 2 базы, в первую, попадают данные от регистрации на сайте, там они на латинице, во вторую, через ID из первой, ядро сервера заносит свои данные, там имена персонажей, бывают они на русском, так вот на странице выводятся "????????" вместо русских символов. Надписи типа "Вход в личный кабинет" работают нормально, знаки вопроса только если слово из базы. База в кодировке UTF-8, страница UTF-8. Помогите решить проблему пожалуйста.

```
$link2 = mysqli_connect ('localhost','root','1','1');
$sql1 = "select name from characters where account='$id'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($link2,$sql1);
while($result3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
```

Comment: Ты какими функциями для работы с БД-то пользуешься, болезный?

Comment: Вот если бы вы показали ваш код которым делаете запрос к базе, легче будет вам помочь.

Comment: После подключения к базе поставьте команду установки кодировки подключения.

Comment: $link2 = mysqli_connect ('localhost','root','1','1');
$sql1 = "select name from characters where account='$id'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($link2,$sql1);
while($result3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
Каким образом ПРАВИЛЬНО устанавливать кодировку получаемых данных? Я пробовал, но наверное не правильно это делал.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/673331/186083

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [При GET запросе все JSON все русские буквы превратились в знаки вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/673292/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-get-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-json-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2)

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");
```

Устанавливаем кодировку получения данных с бд